# MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140, Is this only for VS2015? what is the updated version for VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

This is a general question with regards to MicrosoftAzureTools (Microsoft Azure Tools).

We currently have this installed on our build servers along with Visual Studio 2015.
We are now deprecating VS 2015 and are moving to VS2017.
Is there a newer version of MicrosoftAzureTools for VS 2017?

Is this now part of an Azure Tools CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Workload **Azure development** (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure`) installed in the *Visual Studio Installer*. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) for more information.

There's also versions of the Azure SDK available directly from GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java